# [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400043f9c0

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS App. When I try to get the number of cells for section using a NSMutableArray, I get

> [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60400043f9c0.

Please help. Here is the code:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in _array) {
        NSString *dic = [dict objectForKey:@"product_base"];
            if (dic == nil) {
            }else{
                [_productfliters addObject:dic];
            }
       NSString  *dicMaterial = [dict valueForKey:@"product_material"];
            if (dicMaterial == nil) {
            }else{
                [_productfliters addObject:dicMaterial];
            }

    //                NSMutableDictionary *value  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    //                [value setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"product_size"] forKey:@"ABC"];
        NSString *dicSize = [dict valueForKey:@"product_size"];
        [_productfliters addObject:dicSize];
        }

        self.sectionNames =[_arrayHeading mutableCopy];
        self.sectionItems =[_productfliters mutableCopy];

        NSLog(@"%@",self.sectionItems);


        _tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        _tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
        self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = -1;
        [_tableview reloadData];

- (void)tableViewExpandSection:(NSInteger)section withImage:(UIImageView *)imageView {
        NSArray *sectionData = [self.sectionItems objectAtIndex:section];

        if (sectionData.count == 0) {      //Error this part app crash NSCFString count
            self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = -1;
            return;
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * M_PI) / 180.0);
            }];
            NSMutableArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int i=0; i< sectionData.count; i++) {
                NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
                [arrayOfIndexPaths addObject:index];
            }
            self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = section;
            [_tableview beginUpdates];
            [_tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_tableview endUpdates];
        }
    }
```

Comment: is not a array `NSArray *sectionData` it is the string `NSString *sectionData`

Comment: get value from json hai passing ti sectionItems than also pass to SectionData its datatype array not a string

Comment: can you show me `_array` structure?

Answer (score 0):

You unload strings and put them into `_productfliters`:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in _array) {
        NSString *dic = [dict objectForKey:@"product_base"];
            if (dic == nil) {
            }else{
                [_productfliters addObject:dic];
            }
...
```

You then assign that to `sectionItems`:

```
self.sectionItems =[_productfliters mutableCopy];
```

You then extract one of those strings, but call it an array (even though you put strings in there, so it's a string):

```
NSArray *sectionData = [self.sectionItems objectAtIndex:section];
```

Just because you say `NSArray` here doesn't make it so. You're just telling the compiler what you expect to be true. `objectAtIndex:` return `id` ("any object"). It trusts you when you say it's an `NSArray`, but it isn't true.

You then call `.count` on a `NSString` and crash.

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do here, but you have an array of  strings, not an array of arrays.

Note that ObjC has a new feature called lightweight generics that would possibly have caught this mistake. Had you declared `sectionNames` as either `NSArray<NSString *>*` or `NSArray<NSArray<NSString *>*>*` (depending on which one you wanted this to be), the compiler probably would have thrown a warning (maybe even an error). Lightweight generics are nowhere near as powerful as Swift's generics, but they can catch some type mismatches like this.